# Dynamically change position of div inside another in different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic2

I'm creating an Ionic 2 app in which the user has to select some points on the screen and the values of these coordinates will be used in another screen with a different size. I tried to use rule of three/cross multiplication, but it gave me an approximated value that isn't enough.

[image: points appear in different positions for different screen sizes]

This is what I'm making, using values that looked good in one screen and using the same percentage for another screen with different size:

```
makePosition() {
  let canvasRect = document.getElementById("shapeBoard").getBoundingClientRect();
  let top = this.elementHead.nativeElement.style.top; 
  let left = this.elementHead.nativeElement.style.left; 
  this.elementHead.nativeElement.style.top = canvasRect.top + (canvasRect.height * 1.931634728536)/100 + "px";
  this.elementHead.nativeElement.style.left = canvasRect.left + (canvasRect.width * 48.738582882804224)/100 + "px";
}
```

html: https://codepen.io/jmachado/pen/ybzNzr

Is there a way to change the circle div position dynamically to be always in same position over the image?

Comment: Is size fixed? Like 400 * 600 in iPhone, 600 * 800 in laptop? If yes, then you can use the ratio to calculate the offset on different screens.

Answer (score 0):

I hope these 5 steps will get you a precise positioning:

1) Make the circle position relative to the container the image is in.

2) Make sure the image width is 100% to its container.

3) Store top and left position as a percentage.

4) Set top and left as a percentage% than in px.

5) Make sure the image has no border or margin set, its container has no border or padding.

Percentage left and top will automatically adjust with screen resize without the need of any JavaScript.

Also when you set top and left, it will be relative to the top and left of the circle. You may need to center the circle to the given exact top/left percentage by adding a negative margin of its half of width to the circle.